# Chrome.storage.sync - Will retain their data?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am  using the '`chrome.storage.sync.get/set`' to save my data. My question is, will the data saved using this API will get reset when I close chrome browser window and open it again. Is there any method to clear the data saved when we exit from chrome? I know there is a method '`chrome.storage.sync.clear()`'. But this should happen only when the user exits from chrome.

Comment: You have at least two questions there. It's best to ask **one** question per question.

Answer (score 2):

> will the data saved using this API will get reset when I close chrome browser window and open it again

No, it's saved — not just locally, but also potentially synced to the user's Google account. That's the point of the `sync` storage area. [The documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) says `sync` is like `localStorage`, but synced to the user's account.

If you're using it for transient data, don't. Use `local` instead (as there doesn't appear to be an extension equivalent of session storage) or perhaps just store the data in your extension's runtime environment (it's not clear what you're using this for).

> I know there is a method `chrome.storage.sync.clear()`. But this should happen only when the user exits from chrome.

You'd have to trigger `clear` from an event. Unfortunately, there is not currently an official way for an extension to get notified when Chrome closes ([there's an open issue on it](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=30885)). Hopefully there will be a way at some point, but there isn't currently.

Comment: But it works even if I had signed out from the chrome account

Comment: I found another way it is possible by listening to the port.

Comment: @abhilash: *"But it works even if I had signed out from the chrome account"* Right, because it acts like local storage which **also** syncs to the account *if attached*. *"I found another way it is possible by listening to the port."* Cool! What port?

Answer (score 0):

You're right [chrome.storage.sync.clear()](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage), removes all storage from sync. However, if you want to use that function when the browser 'exists', you'll have to look at the [Processes Api](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/processes).

You would probably want to use this function (from the documentation) :

```
chrome.processes.onExited.addListener(function(){...});
```

It takes `processId` as one of the arguments. So you would just have to get hold of the `processId` for the `browser` process. I found a [relevant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18317327/1083314) for this  on SO only. It suggests you do something like:

```
//Basically loop through all the processes to get the browser's Process Id
var browserId;
chrome.processes.getProcessInfo([], false, function(processes) {
processes.forEach(function(process) {
    if (process.type === 'browser') {
        browserId = process.id;
    }
   });
});
```

Once you have the browser's Process Id, you can add a listener to the `exit` event and do the needful. I hope it gets you started in the right direction.

Comment: If that works, I'm surprised no one's mentioned it [in this Chrome issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=30885).