# How to exit Chrome on STABLE CHANNEL from an extension(in 2023)?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18317327/3809427 says you can exit chrome by [chrome.processes](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/processes/) API. But this is **Dev channel** from 2013 to present (2023).
Is there a way to exit chrome on **stable channel** from Chrome extension?

I want to develop an extension which exit Chrome when a user closes a "Main Window"(I plan to detect it by number of tabs, etc).

Comment: There's only `chrome.debugger` API which you can use to invoke [Browser.close](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Browser/#method-close).

Comment: @lamrongol - **Why** do you want to close Chrome from an extension? (your question sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) to me)

Comment: @ThomasMueller I want to develop an extension which exit Chrome when user closes a "Main Window"(I plan to detect it by number of tabs, etc). This is direct question, I think. But I'll add to the goal.

Comment: @lamrongol - I would use the [chrome.windows](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/windows/) API to close all windows.

Comment: @ThomasMueller Hmmm.... I think simply closing all windows, only last closed window will be shown when booting Chrome again. But similar problem may happen by using [chrome\.processes](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/processes/) or [Browser.close](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Browser/#method-close). Sorry, I have not yet tried these methods because after questioning, I had other things to do.

Comment: @ThomasMueller Sorry for late reply. If booting after windows are closed one-by-one by chrome.windows API, only last window is restored, I think. I need same function as [Exit] menu.

Comment: @wOxxOm I may be mistaken but  Browser.close(Chrome DevTools Protocol) seems be able to used in debugger tool. How can I use it from extension( service_worker.js )?

Comment: Find any example for `chrome.debugger.sendCommand` API and use it with "Browser.close".

Comment: @wOxxOm I tried `chrome.debugger.sendCommand({tabId: 0},'Browser.close')` but error occured. `tabId` or ``extensionId` is needed but this doesn't target a specific tab or extension and irresponsible value such as 0 make error.

Comment: That's why I suggest finding a complete example for using sendCommand properly.

Comment: @wOxxOm Sorry, I tried various way but they all are failed. I watched https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-extensions-samples/blob/main/api-samples/debugger/service-worker.js and added `attach` and `{extensionId: chrome.runtime.id}`  and `tabId` like following( https://gist.github.com/lamrongol/b3941613a49fdb7d26128434ff8c6f90 ). I can't seem to find the way by myself.

Comment: Well, just attach to any tab.

Comment: @wOxxOm Does `const tabId = windows[0].tabs[0].id;  chrome.debugger.attach({ tabId: tabId }` mean "just attach to any tab"? Sorry if I have been mistaken.

Comment: You can use an example of [getting the active tab](/q/1979583) or use the clicked tab in the example you've linked.

Comment: @wOxxOm Sorry for repeating questions but I tried them `Cannot access a chrome-extension:// URL of different extension` error occurred even if normal page. I use `chrome.debugger.sendCommand` not only on `chrome.windows.onRemoved` but also  on ``chrome.action.onClicked``it doesn't change.

Comment: Sounds like the tab contains a page of an extension, in which case you can create a new tab with `url: "about:blank"` and then attach to it.

Comment: @wOxxOm I may be mistaken fundamentally but `Uncaught (in promise) Error: Detached while handling command.` error occurs. I can only upload whole extension folder(this works when clicking toolbar button, not closing window). https://file.io/whhLoHVnie5W

Comment: I see `'Browser.close' wasn't found`, which means either a bug or an intentional restriction. Try reporting it in https://crbug.com.